# Venn plot for 6 sets with labels & sub-/super-scripts using R code

Tags: r, venn-diagram

How to change the set name with sub-/super-scripts.

```
library(venn);
input = list();
input[[1]] = sample(1:50, 10);
input[[2]] = sample(1:50, 10);
input[[3]] =  sample(1:50, 10);
input[[4]] = sample(1:50, 10);
input[[5]] = sample(1:50, 10);
input[[6]] =  sample(1:50, 10);
names(input) = c("alpha[1]", "beta^2", "C", "D","E","F")
venn(input)
```

Comment: You can get the second one by using the unicode character for superscript 2 : beta²  or did you really want β²

Comment: Thanks your reply. But, I can't use 'expression' or 'quote' to add the superscript.